# how to supply a access token while making a graph api call

Tags: facebook, http

I'm trying to a list of a fb page's events from a website using php or javascript, and after some googling it seems that the correct way to do it is using the api call

```
http://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/events
```

but when I actually make the call, it requires authentication. I assume this is where it needs the access token from a app?

how do I actually supply the access token with that call?

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the access token like this :

```
XYZ_API?access_token=TOKEN
```