# In a Firebase Angular application, how to programmatically like a Facebook post when authenticated via Facebook

Tags: angularjs, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, firebase, angularfire

I got my Firebase Angular application working with Facebook authentication. The application was originally generated with Yeoman firebase/generator-angularfire.

According to the [Facebook Graphi API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes) to like a post, I can do:

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/{object-id}/likes",
    "POST",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

In the case of a Firebase Angular application how can I get a reference to FB and like a post programmatically for a user who is authenticated with Facebook?

There are angular-facebook libraries [out](https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook) [there](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angulike). But I'm reluctant to use those since Facebook authentication is already provided by the AngularFire application.

Comment: Related, but about twitter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378608/access-twitter-api-after-firebase-simple-login

Comment: Do not post multiple questions embedded in the description of your original. Post a new question. Also, "how to ..." is generally going to be too broad for Stack Overflow. That's more the purview of tutorials and how-to blogs.

Comment: @Kato. Thanks for the feedback. I changed the question and made it specific. Will create a new question about liking the page later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give this a stab, since there haven't been any knowledgable takers thus far. Bear with me as I'm not an expert at the Facebook API.

As far as I understand, you can't authenticate to the Facebook API using your Firebase token. The Facebook token is stored in the [facebook.authToken setting](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html#section-logging-in), but I believe that won't help, since Facebook requires you to create the token with expanded permissions to access nearly any API features.

An alternative would be to authenticate against Facebook's OAuth directly, requesting the scope needed for likes, and then to pass that token into Firebase using [authWithOAuthToken()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithoauthtoken.html)

Given all of this, I'm not convinced you need authentication and the API to accomplish this from a client. Consider [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button), which provides tools for creating a like button that you can post on your web page. It would presumably utilize Facebook OAuth as well--details are scarce on how exactly it works--which should mean the Firebase login would be sufficient.

Comment: The Firebase token is indeed not suited as an access token to [call the graph api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165374/how-to-supply-a-access-token-while-making-a-graph-api-call) with. You’d get a 400 {message: "Bad signature”, type: “OAuthException”}. The alternative which is also [described here](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/03/sign-into-firebase-with-facebook-using-ionic-framework/), seems like the way to go. Or a simple button and not use the api at all. Thanks for giving me some pointers.